# jQuery draggable helper glitch in chrome

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable, helper

I tried everything I know to solve this problem, but no success. My site is working completely in IE and FF. in Chrome there is a little glitch - without a reason.

I have two tables. A source table and a destination one. I am dragging table-rows (tr) from source to destination or inside the destination table.
When I start dragging the row, it is cloned by a **self-made helper** to drag it freely around.

```
helper: function(event){
/* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
   return $('<div class="dragged-row"><table></table></div>')
          .find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone().addClass("dragged-row")).end();
},
```

(I got this code from the internet)

When I use the helper 'clone' instead, the problem is gone, but my class is not applied (the purple background-color).

**I have created a minimized example on http://jsfiddle.net/jt3LX/**

You can drag one row. If you start dragging, both lines will get purple (this is wanted). But in chrome the first row of the table is getting BIG (why????).

Could you help me with one (or both) of these possibilities:

- Find another way to make the background of the source purple,
- Find the problem of the "bigging the first row"-glitch.

Many thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line instead : `return $(this).addClass("dragged-row").clone();`

http://jsfiddle.net/jt3LX/2/

```
    $(".drag tr").not(".tableHead").draggable({
        helper: function(event){
            /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
            return $(this).addClass("dragged-row").clone();
        },
        start: function(event, ui){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#aaaaff");

            c.tr = this;
            c.helper = ui.helper;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $(this).css("background-color", '');

            c.tr = null;
            c.helper = null;
        }
    });
```

Tested on FF, IE9 and Chrome

Comment: Does not work for me: http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/3681/e6a9c107de504d8497560de.png

Comment: What is not working? Is it about the line color? Force it like this : `return $(this).addClass("dragged-row").clone().css('cssText','background-color: #aaaaff');`

Comment: Ok, it's not 100% perfect now, but I think, I can work with it - I thank you very much! I will try my luck and report back.

Comment: Well, I tested some things and I have to say, that your solution does not make me happy. The cloned row is not handlable by me. It does not use the css-classes, it is not configurable like all the other rows. That's why I used the table-fake-helper before. Now I have to choose: A big glitch in chrome or a little glitch in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements you stated are:

- Find another way to make the background of the source purple,
- Find the problem of the "bigging the first row"-glitch.

fiddle solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jt3LX/6/

for your first point `i am guessing` that you `want to make background color of purple when drop happens.`

So you have to do at this part of the code:

```
stop: function(event, ui){
            $(this).css("background-color", '#aaaaff'); // give purple color code here

            c.tr = null;
            c.helper = null;
        }
```

and the bigging issue i see that you dont have the width specified to the tables thats make the width to the full when drag executed and clone gets in the picture.

So for this i just gave some width to the tables:

```
.main, .dropTable{position:relative; width:606px;}
```

so bigging of the dragging tr not happening now.

i hope you are after this kind of solution and i am guessing this will help you.

Comment: I am sorry, you misunderstood me. First requirement means, it should be purple while dragging. I already tested to give it a size - it did not work - I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in Chrome 24. Which version of chrome are you using? Can u upgrade to the latest version of chrome and let me know if you are having the issue ?